# How To Redirect The StdErr Of A Command Called Inside of An Until Loop *Expression* To A Function

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to perform some custom function *until* a process exits. What I am attempting to do is until that process exits, I want to redirect the stderr to a custom function for further analysis and processing.

So far I have this:

```
    ncommand="sudo command --flag --flag arg --flag arg"

    custom_function() {
       while read data; do
            printf "%s" "$data"
       done
    }

    until [[ $(eval $ncommand) 2>&1 | custom_function -eq 0]]
    do
      # do nothing here but maybe a log
    done
```

As of now, this is giving me a syntax error. How can I get this done? Is it possible or should I go a different route?

Comment: Make this line with space before close brackets: `until [[ $(eval $ncommand) 2>&1 | custom_function -eq 0 ]]`

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thanks for your reply. I'm still getting the syntax error: `./launch.sh: line 25: conditional binary operator expected
./launch.sh: line 25: syntax error near `2>'
./launch.sh: line 25: `until [[ $(eval $ncommand) 2>&1 | custom_function -eq 0 ]]`